# Why does a single-process MRI ruby program actually result to two processes on Ubuntu?

Tags: ruby, ubuntu

I found that a single-process ruby program would cause actually **two** processes on Ubuntu. I tested it on Ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04 with ruby 2.3.1

I wrote a simple ruby script `sleep.rb` with the content as blow:

```
sleep 1000
```

Then I opened htop, added a filter `ruby sleep.rb`. And I ran `ruby sleep.rb`. I found that there were two processes there. `pstree -sp $PID` told me that one of them is forked from another.

(I tried another language, python. Only **one** python process existed. I also tried ruby on OSX 10.11, where only **one** ruby process listed in htop.)

But why? Thank you!

Comment: Please add some output of the `pstree` command. Generally, Ruby doesn't spawn new processes on its own (also you can do it). If you have multiple processes, the general reason is that you have wrapper scripts around your `ruby` executable, e.g. from rvm or similar tools which can result in a process tree.